# How to uninstall a program on Windows 7 via Linux

Tags: windows-7, uninstall, ubuntu-11.04, maintenance

I have a dual boot system which has gathered some problem with malware or some other problem in Windows 7 due to which I am unable to use Windows 7.

Is it possible to uninstall Windows 7 programs by booting in Ubuntu (deleting some files of Windows 7)?

Per my previous question, [High memory usage on Windows 7 unable to open browser](https://superuser.com/questions/526979/high-memory-usage-on-windows-7-unable-to-open-browser), I can't use Windows in normal mode.

The comment by @mmmc below suggests that this is a possibility: [Fix the Windows Registry from a Linux Thumb Drive](http://lifehacker.com/5584762/edit-the-windows-registry-from-a-linux-thumb-drive)

Comment: Yes, You can delete the files, you won't be able to modify in registry enteries.  Why don't you just use the proper tools while booted in windows to remove the malware?

Comment: In the **general case**, no, it is not possible, because any given program might do any sort of arbitrary system customization when it installs: file associations, registry writes, kernel modules (drivers), user creation/deletion, Windows services, writing to the installer database, InstallShield functionality, MSI functionality, Start Menu shortcuts, etc. Properly uninstalling can only be done from native Windows itself. Also, deleting random files is **not** a good way of troubleshooting. You should report the specific symptoms you are experiencing, in a new question.

Comment: my system is a dual boot since I am unable to use it in Windows 7 as question has been updated so this idea came to my mind if I can uninstall some way by Ubuntu Linux these days have gone very advanced so I thought this might be a possiblilty hence asked

Comment: @RegisteredUser I have to ask, why can't you reformat Windows 7 from the W7 DVD? Your question reads as if you want to only solve this via the Ubuntu OS?

Comment: yes the DVD rom is corrupt it is not possible to format it via DVD

Comment: @RegisteredUser Kindly remove that "UPDATE 2" comment. If you want your question to be reopened, consider editing it to clarify your problem, rather than calling everyone who voted to close it ignorant.

Comment: I really don't understand why this question is closed. It makes perfect sense to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm leaving my previous answer but it is inaccurate. There are ways to do what you want to do but it is as dangerous as teasing with fire one might say. 
There is a [software](http://lifehacker.com/5584762/edit-the-windows-registry-from-a-linux-thumb-drive) which is capable of editing registry files from command line of linux shell.

If you have a list of files that were created by particular software installation and at the same time the list of all registry keys created and/or modified during and after installation - or even better - the registry backup from before the software installation - you could reverse the changes made in the registry by installation process.

Previous answer (Somehow I think this one is better as it will prevent more people from trying to edit Windows registry from linux - even if it is wrong ;)  ):

> In short - no. Not directly. You can remove some files from `NTFS`
>   partions but you cannot change registry keys directly - most of the
>   software out there is adding some keys to Windows registry. This
>   cannot be edited while Windows is turned off. However you can create a
>   bat(or vbs) file with commands that will remove registry keys and add
>   this bat file to the `startup` folder of Windows users (inside their
>   profile) - this has a potential of removing the keys from registry if
>   user has proper rights and/or is able to elevate rights to level of
>   system admin - only then registry can be edited. Placing a file in
>   specific folder could be of course done from the Linux level but the
>   process of complete uninstall can be achieved only when Windows OS is
>   running.

Take my advise and do not do it. There are better easier ways from Windows itself.

Comment: @DaveRook Actually it looks like i was wrong. Totally. http://lifehacker.com/5584762/edit-the-windows-registry-from-a-linux-thumb-drive . It seems that there are tools that allow editing registry on the command line level for example from Linux booted from USB. So if someone would know exacly which registry keys needs to be removed to uninstall particular software - this in fact could be done from Linux.

Comment: thanks based on some feedback here and some other logics using Linux I have been able to solve my problem  can check this thread http://superuser.com/questions/526979/high-memory-usage-on-windows-7-unable-to-open-browser/527618#527618

Comment: Why even bother with a Linux-based non-GUI registry editor (who knows how well it understands the registry structure and all data types)? I mean, for simple password blanking it might be fine, but for full-blown registry editing it would be *far* simpler to boot from a WinPE disc/USB, attach the offline registry using a good Windows registry editor and edit it as usual.